# Can't update state using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update the state of my component with useState in a register functional component。
when user input an invalid email address and click the submit button,
the following piece of code will return an error message

```
let response= await axios.post("/api/user/register",new_user,config);
```

I want to set error message into formData with this piece of code .

```
        let response= await axios.post("/api/user/register",new_user,config);
        if(response.data.errnum!==0){
            setFormData({...formData,errors:response.data.message})
            console.log(formData);
        }
```

but the value of errors is empty,like this [image: result screenshot]

What should I do to set error message into formData?

Here is my code:

```js
import React ,{useState}from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

function Register() {

    const [formData,setFormData]=useState({
        name:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        password2:"",
        errors:{}
    });

    const {name,email,password,password2}=formData;

    const setValue= e =>setFormData({...formData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    
    const submitData=async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(password!==password2){
            console.log("passwords do not match ");
        }else{
            let new_user={name,email,password,}
            try{
                let config={
                    header:{
                        'Content-Type':'applicaiton/json'
                    }
                }
                let response= await axios.post("/api/user/register",new_user,config);
                
                if(response.data.errnum!==0){
                    setFormData({...formData,errors:response.data.message})
                    console.log(formData);
                }
            }catch(error){
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <section className="container">
                <h1 className="large text-primary">Sign Up</h1>
                <p className="lead"><i className="fas fa-user"></i> Create Your Account</p>

                <form className="form" onSubmit={e=>submitData(e)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Name" 
                        name="name"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={e=>setValue(e)}
                         required />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">

                        <input 
                        type="email" 
                        placeholder="Email Address" 
                        onChange={e=>setValue(e)}
                        value={email}
                        name="email" />
                        <small className="form-text">This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use aGravatar email</small>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        onChange={e=>setValue(e)}
                        value={password}
                        name="password"
                        minLength="6"
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Confirm Password"
                        onChange={e=>setValue(e)}
                        value={password2}
                        name="password2"
                        minLength="6"
                    />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
                </form>
                <p className="my-1">
                    Already have an account? <a href="login.html">Sign In</a>
                </p>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

Comment: try `setState(prevValue => ({...prevValue, key: value}))`

Comment: thank you for your answer.I tried it ,but this doesn't work.             
`setFormData(prevValue => ({...prevValue, errors: response.data.message}))`

Comment: man react doesn't tigger state update immediately it's happening asynchronously so u need to use useffect to check state update like so : `useEffect(()=>{console.log(formData)},[formData] })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing wrong is that you are saving and object inside another object

```
const [formData,setFormData]=useState({
    name:"",
    email:"",
    password:"",
    password2:"",
    errors:{}
});
```

formData is an object while errors is also an object.To go for a better approach make a seperate state for errors and append all the errors coming through those messages in an error object.
If you write a message in errors object where it is defined it will give you error

```
errors:{"hi","bye"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your code. What you are trying to do is console the `state` as soon as you are setting it up.

`setState` is asynchronous which means you can’t call it on one line and assume the state has changed on the next.

If you check [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

I'd suggest you use `useEffect` and then check for change in data of your state.

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(formData)
}, [formData])
```